# generating animation in different spots in view randomly

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, animation

Hello I am new to animations and just started playing around with it recently. I want to have a circle (ring) displayed that goes from a small ring to a large ring, dissapears and then does the process all over again except in a different location.

To do this I have created 6 different image sizes of the same ring. The following code is how I have done it but I do not know how to repeat the process (AkA it runs the method but the location of the ring stays the same, I need to loop the random number generator but don't know  when to do a check if the image has stopped). If this is not the right way to go about this, please let me know! P.S. The ring looks very ugly by the time it gets to its largest stage, not sure why.

Thanks

```
-(void) doWork
{

NSInteger number;
NSInteger number2;
NSLog (@"here");

number = (arc4random()%100)+1; 
number2 = (arc4random()%100)+1; 
 NSLog (@" hello numer1: %d", number);
 NSLog (@" hello numer2: %d", number2);

imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(number, number2, 135, 135)]; 

imageView.animationImages= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"smallestRing.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"smallRing.png"], 
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mediumRing.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"large2Ring.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"largeRing.png"], nil]; 

imageView.animationDuration= 2.5;
imageView.animationRepeatCount= 0;
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

[imageView startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];

/*[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(doWork) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];*/

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if resizing (or other transforming such as rotation or transition) is the only animation you need, you could use method +animateWithDuration (you can found description [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html))

it will look like:

```
-(void) doWork
{

NSInteger number;
NSInteger number2;
NSLog (@"here");

number = (arc4random()%100)+1; 
number2 = (arc4random()%100)+1; 
 NSLog (@" hello numer1: %d", number);
 NSLog (@" hello numer2: %d", number2);

imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(number, number2, 135, 135)]; 

imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"largeRing.png"];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];

[self animate:imageView enlarge:YES];
}

-(void) animate:(UIImageView*)imageView enlarge:(BOOL)flag
{
if (flag) 
{
// then animating is starting
// and imageView will appear in random point of view
    int randomX = arc4random()%self.view.frame.size.width;
    int randomY = arc4random()%self.view.frame.size.height;
    imageView.center = CGPointMake(randomX, randomY);
}

double scale = flag ? 2 : 0.5;
[UIView animateWithDuration:5
         animations:^{ imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale,scale); }
         completion:^(BOOL finished){ [self animate:imageView: enlarge:!flag]; }];
}
```

Comment: I like the animation it gives, its clean. Thanks for your help but it does not put the circle into random positions on the screen after each animation finishes. Do you know how to do this? Thanks. Will accept anyway

Comment: edit code to reach this: when method -animate is called and if flag is YES, it means that animation will start, so we set the center of imageView to random point of self.view. You can change this to "if (flag == NO)" to put circle into random point after animation ends, but then the first time it will not be in random point

Comment: Thanks so much again, really appreciate it. If you could just tell me one last thing, how could I stop the animation? Specifically when view is unloading (it seems to be taking away lots of cpu...). Thanks

Comment: try [self.view.layer removeAllAnimations];

Comment: Didn't seem to work. I put a NSLog() at the top of the animate function and I think its strange that as soon as I leave the view with the animation happening, the nsLog() goes off like crazy... every second or so. Do you know why? Thanks again

Comment: maybe it is not enough to call -removeAllAnimations, add something like "if (animationOver == YES) return;" into beginning of -animate:enlarge:, where animationOver - BOOL value, which shows that you have left view. Set it to YES in -viewDidUnload and -animate:enlarge: will be called no more

Answer (score 1):

You can query the bool isAnimating in order to determine if the animation of the UIImageView ended

P.S:
Probably it looks ugly because of

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Try something like

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
```